# Typescript + React: Typing a functional wrapper component that extends a given class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component that wraps a class component and passes all but one prop to it:

```
import React, { Component, ComponentType } from 'react'
import Layout from './components/LayoutComponent'
import { Route } from 'react-router'

type LayoutRouteProps = {
    component: ComponentType,
}

const DashboardLayoutRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}: LayoutRouteProps) => {
    const render = (matchProps: any) => (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...matchProps} />
        </Layout>
    )

    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={render} />
    )
}
```

How do I import props definition for `Route` and add them to `type LayoutRouteProps`?